# Protractor NodeJS Asynch: Resolving a promise as a base case in recursive function

Tags: loops, protractor

I'm trying to use a Protractor resolved promise in a base case of a recursive function. It seems like this should work as I think I am fully resolving the promise in the base case. In the code below the termination return is reached before the base case. This is just a simple function that keeps trying to click a seat in a flash element.

```
this.selectOpenSeat = function(startX, startY) {

      // base case
      this.btnNext.isEnabled().then(function(status) {
        if (status) {
          console.log('Seat Staus:' + status);
          return;
        }
      });

      // termination
      if (startX > 315) {
        console.log('Out of bounds!');
        return;
      }

      // call selectOpenSeat() again
      console.log('Trying to select open seat' + startX);
      this.selectSeatByXY(startX, startY);

      // Iterate
      startX += 15;

      // Recursion
      this.selectOpenSeat(startX, startY);
  };

 selectOpenSeat(210, 140);
```

Here is what the console logs:

```
Trying to select open seat210
Trying to select open seat225
Trying to select open seat240
Trying to select open seat255
Trying to select open seat270
Trying to select open seat285
Trying to select open seat300
Trying to select open seat315
Out of bounds!
Seat Staus:true
Seat Staus:true
Seat Staus:true
Seat Staus:true
Seat Staus:true
Seat Staus:true
Seat Staus:true
Seat Staus:true
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the entire promise form the `selectOpenSeat` method to make it synchronize.I guess this should solve your problem.,

```
this.selectOpenSeat = function(startX, startY) {
   var self = this;
   return self.btnNext.isEnabled().then(function(status) {
   console.log("Status:"+status+" and startX:"+startX);
        if (status || startX > 315) {
            console.log("Out of bound or button enabled");
            return;
        }
       self.selectSeatByXY(startX, startY);
       startX += 15;
       self.selectOpenSeat(startX, startY);
   });
};
```